# Issue in sql server with join query

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, distinct

I have **four tables** for join I am trying to **join with views** in sql server. i have successfully done join query and retrieving data from multiple table with join query. But I Execute the same query sql server shows the different result every time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
               dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.ID
             , dbo.tbl_verifyCnicDetails.fID
             , dbo.tbl_verifyCnicDetails.colGRName
             , dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.colCompanyID
             , dbo.tbl_verifyAvailableFingers.colCNIC
             , dbo.tbl_agent.agent_id
             , dbo.tbl_agent.colIMSI
             , dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.colDate
             , dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.colStatusMessage
FROM dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_verifyCnicDetails      
                         ON dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.ID = dbo.tbl_verifyCnicDetails.fID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_verifyAvailableFingers 
                         ON dbo.tbl_verifyFinger2.colCNIC = dbo.tbl_verifyAvailableFingers.colCNIC 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_agent 
                         ON dbo.tbl_verifyAvailableFingers.colIMSI = dbo.tbl_agent.colIMSI
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without views definition. I can just guess that some kind of window function is used there such as ROW_NUMBER or something

Comment: thanks but over all sql server result change after every time i execute this query

Comment: are there only tables in that query?

Comment: yes there are only tables in that query

Comment: You need to show definitions of at least the columns used in the query.

Comment: different result means different column values or different quantity?

Comment: No, Full Row Changed When Execute This Query... For Example... My First Row Data IS (1 , Obaid , obaid@abce.com) and Second Row Data Is (2, Ubaid, ubaid@abcd.com).. when i execute these query the data was change this row is moving up and down....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause SQL Server not allow to use `ORDER By` clause inside views, to get same preview of result every time, you must include `ORDER BY` clause in you outer `SELECT` query, at the end of query.

Of course, carefully choose columns in `ORDER BY` clause, because it must be deterministic which guarantee that every time sorted result will be the same and moving your rows up and down will not be presented more.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM schema_name.view_name AS v
ORDER BY
    v.column_name (ASC|DESC) --If ommiting directions, ASC is the default
```